# Charging 10 1.2V nicd batteries

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, battery-charging

I have 10 x 1.2V Sanyo NiCd batteries. They are connected in series. I would like to charge them. The thing is, I don't have a charger. I looked up chargers and they are all quite expensive(I live in India). I would like to know what voltage AC to DC adapter should I get to charge them.

What are the risks involved in doing so?

Could you also suggest me some cheap ways of getting the batteries charged?

Comment: Something occurred to me. If you can separate the batteries from the battery pack you can charge them in groups. Lower voltage sources like 5 and 12V are _much_ cheaper to find than larger ones.

Comment: they are all soldered, i cant remove them

Comment: That's unfortunate. 5V adapters are very cheap and easy to find because of USB and a 12V car battery is too low a voltage. You'll have to dig up a larger source I'm afraid.

Comment: C is the mA rate corresponding to the cell mAh capacity so eg for a 1200 mAh cell, C = 1200 mA. If they are NiCd you cam safely trickle charge them at  C/10 - notionally for ever but preferably for about 1 day overall. 24 hrs x c/10 ENSURES all cells are well charged and helps balance the pack. Even about 18 hours at C/10 is enough from fully discharged. Overcharging at > C/10 will damage cells. || NB NiCd and NimH differ - Modern high capacity NimH MUST NOT be trickle charged past full capacity. (eg an AA NimH of 1800 mAh or more is best never trickle charged. )

Comment: Use a old 14.4v drill charger that will do it

Comment: @Brightspark: Your answer, converted to comment, is careless. (1) The charger would have to suit NiCd chemistry. (2) It would have to match the battery capacity. Over-charging would damage the cells. Under-charging would take too long. This is all explained in the answer that was accepted two years ago. Did you read it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fully charged voltage on 10 NiCd batteries is about 1.4V * 10 = 14V. So the first thing you will need is a voltage source higher than that. To keep it safe you really need 1.5 * 10 = 15V minimum.

NiCd batteries are charged with a constant current. You don't say what the rating on your batteries are, but let us assume they are 500mAhr. Trickle charging them is C/10 or 50mA. That's nice and safe and will fully charge your batteries in 15hrs (you add 50% to the time because charging is not 100% efficient)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc6t8M.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To keep things cheap you can use a resistor to supply this current and calculate the resistor value as:

$$R = \frac{V_{source} - V_{batpack}}{I}$$

Let's say you find an 18V source. Then 18 - 14 = 4V. And you want to charge at 50mA so your resistor value is 80 ohms. 100 is the closest you will get which will charge at: 4/100 = 40mA.

Edit:

I should add that the current will vary as the batteries charge. So a discharged battery at 1.1V will charge at (18 - 11) / 100 = 70mA. This current will fall to 40mA as the battery comes up to full charge.

With a C/10 charge rate, 14 hours is safe even if they are partially charged to begin with. You are "trickle charging" at a "charging rate" and the batteries are designed to full cope with this rate. Any faster than this you will have to verify they are charged - the battery pack voltage will be above the nominal 1.25V * 10 = 12.5V when you disconnect the charger and check with a meter. At 1.45V/cell (or anything above 14V for your pack), they are fully charged. Expensive chargers do all this for you.

You can trickle charge at a "top up" rate by adjusting to C/20. So for 500mA batteries, trickle charge at 500/20 = 25mA. You can do this indefinately without damage. Although to charge at this rate from discharged will take, well, days!

Comment: So what exactly should I get from the shop?  Should I get a 18v adapter? Edit: they are 2500 mah

Comment: It depends what is cheapest for you. 18V would be fine but anything above that (within reason) is fine too. Common voltages are 24V for trucks for example. An old truck battery and an appropriate resistor would work fine!

Comment: Note that using this circuit, its the responsibility of the user to disconnect the batteries once they are charged. Otherwise it may damage the cells (I am not sure about NiCd though). Its non-trivial to check if a cell is fully charged.

Comment: Thanks to Ricardo for Mathjaxing the equation. Must read the help more ;-)

Comment: How do I make sure if the batteries are charged ?I can assume 24v to be the limit?

Comment: Commercial chargers perform continuous measurements to monitor the voltage signature and the temperature while charging. NiCd show a rapid temperature increase towards the end of charge, for example.

Comment: could you please give a diagram ?

Comment: I'll edit my post in a minute and add some more details on charging rates.

Comment: Maybe [read this](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_nickel_based_batteries).

Comment: could you please provide a diagram ? Explain this line :To keep things cheap you can use a resistor to supply this current and calculate the resistor value as. 
Do I add the Resistance in series to the power supply ?

Comment: A fully charged battery is 1.45V. So the pack will never be above 14.5V. With a 24V source and 2500mAh battery - 14 hour rate is 250mA. So (24V - 14.5)/0.250 = 38 ohms. Get a 39 ohm resistor which can cope with at least 3.5 watts. I think you'll need a 5W resistor. Pretty chunky!

Comment: @harvey: Apologies - I wasn't clear enough. Yes. Your only components are the voltage source and the resistor. You add the resistor in series with the power supply.

Comment: so its like POWER->resistance to + , then the other end to the + of the batter, and then common ground?

Comment: Yes. I've added a circuit. It always turns out *huge* but you get the idea.

Comment: Can you just give me voltages for full down ? and how do I discharge the batteries safely ?

Comment: Fully discharged? Anything below 1V/cell (10V for your pack) is fully discharged. You can use a resistor to discharge a pack but if the pack voltage falls below 10V you will start damaging the cells.

Comment: That assumes identical cells. In real life the cells have slightly different capcity and you would have in the 10 Volt pack for example 5 cells at ~1.2V, 4 cells at ~1.1 Volt and one (the weakest cell) taking damage at -0.4 Volt. Thats why you don't want those packs to discharge too depply.

Comment: One problem is, I was unable to find any adapter with current output of about 250mA (C/10), I am getting them in the Range of 1A, 500mA etc. What do I do to reduce the current my Batteries will get?

Comment: Standard DC power adapters are voltage sources - they supply a constant voltage, the current that is drawn by the load depends entirely on the load. The current rating of the adapter is the *maximum* it can provide.

Comment: yes, but in this case, where its connected to a battery, won't it always provide the maximum that it can?

Comment: If I have a DC generator, which voltage should I set it to? I noticed that as I increase the voltage the charging current is also rising (which is good, faster charging), but I'm afraid to damage the battery with high voltage. Is there a limit?